# Microsoft Outlook - suggested email recipients with auto-complete - Office 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

We use Office 365 to manage and emails. I have Outlook installed on 2 different computers.

We are having a problem with the suggested email recipient on a new install.

Some accounts have multiple aliases so chas@example is an alias of dave@example. On 365 admin, the user display name is "Dave". In Outlook, if I type dave@example it suggests "Chas". Is there anyway to edit this?

There is an option to "Empty Auto-Complete List" - is that local to this laptop? How will it rebuild the suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue occur on web mail?

If it is the same as on Outlook 365, it may be related to the account. it's suggested that you could create a contact for chas@example to name it Chas and also create a contact for dave@example to name it Dave to check if there're any differences.

> There is an option to "Empty Auto-Complete List" - is that local to this laptop? How will it rebuild the suggestions?

The location of Auto-Complete List which stores names and addresses that appear in Recent People is as follows: ％USERPROFILE％\ AppData \ Local \ Microsoft \ Outlook \ RoamCache.

As I know, other suggestion list can't be removed. For information, please refer to: [Manage suggested recipients in the To, Cc, and Bcc boxes with Auto-Complete](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-suggested-recipients-in-the-to-cc-and-bcc-boxes-with-auto-complete-dbe46e31-c098-4881-8cf7-66b037bce23e).
[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.